# FindGeometricTransform not working properly for a simple problem

Tags: functions, bugs, debugging, geometric-transform

I am surprised why `FindGeometricTransform` is failing to automatically register or align two sets of points that are drawn from a `Ball`. I know that one can change the `Method` and the `TransformationClass` to get the result but the developers mention that the function takes the most appropriate settings for alignment by default. This does not seem to be the case.

I have tried this in Version 12.0 running on Windows 10

```
pts1 = RandomPoint[Ball[], 5000];
pts2 = RandomPoint[Ball[{1.5, 1.5, 1.5}, 1], 5000];

{err, geomtrans} = FindGeometricTransform[pts1, pts2];

Graphics3D[{Red, Point@pts1, Blue, Point@(geomtrans@pts2)}]
```

the bizarre result is below (looks like the Solver chose RANSAC).

[image]

The same result can be obtained by using `FindGeometricTransform[pts1, pts2, Method -> "RANSAC"]`;

Keeping the `Method -> "RANSAC"` the result is still wrong (off centered) if I specify `TransformationClass -> "Translation"`

[image]

The result is totally wrong if I specify `TransformationClass -> "Rigid"` with `Method` specified as `RANSAC`. The solver should not do any `ScalingTransform`

[image]

The only time it gives me correct result is if I use `Method -> "Linear"` with either `TransformationClass -> "Translation"` or `TransformationClass -> "Rigid"`

[image]

**I do not understand whether to consider this to be a bug since some transformations are doing scaling albeit the fact that the transformation should be rigid??**

---

This is not an answer but rather something I do not understand. This seems quite Bizarre to me the more I think about it.

```
pts = RandomPoint[Ball[], 10000];
pts2 = Map[RandomReal[{0, 0.5}, 3] + {1.5, 0, 0} + # &, pts]; (* points with noise and translation *)
pts3 = RandomPoint[Ball[{1.5, 0, 0}, 1], 10000]; (* points sampled from another ball that is only translated *)

{err, geom} = FindGeometricTransform[pts, pts2, Method -> "RANSAC",TransformationClass -> "Rigid"];

{err, geom3} = FindGeometricTransform[pts, pts2, Method -> "Linear",TransformationClass -> "Rigid"];

{err2, geom2} = FindGeometricTransform[pts,pts3,Method ->"RANSAC", TransformationClass -> "Rigid"];

{err2, geom4} = FindGeometricTransform[pts,pts3,Method ->"Linear", TransformationClass -> "Rigid"];
```

Now let us draw the results.

The first registration with "RANSAC" `geom` seems reasonable although I can observe a little scaling when compareed to "Linear" `geom3`

`{Graphics3D[{Red, Point@pts, Blue, Point@pts2}], Graphics3D[{Red, Point@pts,Blue, Point@geom@pts2}],Graphics3D[{Red, Point@pts, Blue, Point@geom3@pts2}]}`

[image]

The second one is incorrect with "RANSAC" `geom2` and correct with "Linear" `geom4`

`{Graphics3D[{Red,Point@pts, Blue, Point@pts3}],Graphics3D[{Red,Point@pts,Blue, Point@geom2@pts3}],Graphics3D[{Red, Point@pts, Blue, Point@geom4@pts3}]}`

[image]

Comment: Your point sets aren't related. That's why `FindGeometricTransformation` fails.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don't understand what you mean by not related. They don't need to be related but can nevertheless be registered using an error minimization scheme. `Method -> Linear` works so why not the default settings.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what is possible. Giving two different sets of 5000 random points on two different spheres and you are asking for one function that maps the second set one to one onto the first set. Imagine what horrible function that must be! In any case, there is certainly no affine or  perspective transformation function that can do this. However, it would work if you would translate and rotate the first sphere, with the points attached, to get the second set.

Comment: @ AliHashmi What transformation do you expect from the mapping `p1->p2`?

Comment: @DanielHuber I disagree. I guess check what registrations functions do. They can align two images with some degree of noise between them. You dont need to manually rotate or translate them. The whole point is to find the transformation matrix. The points of one ball are features in space that are offsets from the second ball.

Comment: @DanielHuber in the last part of my post I show that the function works but only if you choose `Method -> "Linear"`. I am curious why it is failing for the default case when no settings are specified. Also RANSAC should not fail or scale things on a simple problem

Comment: That can not be true. Try it out, if every point of the second set is transformed into the corresponding point of the first set. A linear transformation can only rotate or stretch a rigid body, but it can  not map  unrelated sets onto each other.

Comment: @DanielHuber I do not need an exact mapping. The linear transformation can minimize the error though. If two set are far away larger error and if the two point sets are close together then smaller error. The application of `FindGeometricTransform` gives an error along with the matrix. The whole point is to find a matrix that minimizes the error during registration.

Comment: I agree that "Rigid" should only to rotation and translation. "Similarity" should do in addition stretching.